# Make footer stay always out of view at the bottom of page

Tags: css, footer

I want to create a footer that always stays at the bottom of the page but also out of view, meaning that if the user doesn't scroll, it shouldn't be visible even when the page content is not enough to push it down enough.

Here's a quick illustration:
[image]

I tried searching online but there was no asnwer to this specific case.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.content-area {
    --sidebar-width: calc(2rem + 35px);
    margin-left: calc(var(--sidebar-width) + 2rem);
    width: calc(100% - var(--sidebar-width) - 4rem);
    position: relative;
    top: calc(5rem + 1px + 2rem);
}

footer {
    background-color: var(--light-black);
    margin: 0;
    width: calc(100% - var(--sidebar-width));
    min-height: 15rem;
    height: fit-content;
    position: absolute;
    left: var(--sidebar-width);
    bottom: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
        "section section section"
        "branding branding branding";
}
```

```html
<div class="content-area"></div>
<footer>
    <div>
        <p>Links</p>
        <a href="https://status.example.com" target="_blank">Status</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <hr>
        <h1>Text</h1>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Did you try anything to achieve your expectation? Please add your efforts

Comment: Yes i tried using absolute positioning and the footer stays at the bottom of the page but at the same time it covers the page content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easily doable by wrappign all content with exception of the footer in a container. Then simply apply `min-height: 100vh` to that wrapping container and the footer will by default stay out of vieport unless you scrolled down.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>Header / Navbar</header>
  <main>Main Content</main>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```